# Making a flexible Interface for CRM App

Tags: interaction-design, app, crm

I am working on a tablet app that will be used as a CRM, But as a app it needs to be flexible to have provisions for all the cases that could arise while interacting with a customer. As we cant put "all" of them we need to have a app that can include the changes with minor effect on interaction and efficiency of people using them. So what can be the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach it like any other project. Talk to the end user or stakeholders and figure out:

1. Their workflow and create multiple task flows to map out all the steps
2. Needs arising for that workflow
3. Problems from workflow that requires special attention
4. Define the features
5. Create the interface based on all the above items, always keeping in mind the flow for each and the user's needs when performing the workflow.
6. Talk to the end user constantly to test the prototype and receive feedback.